# Does "rated torque" (kg.cm) directly apply to "lead screws"?

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, torque, actuator

I am making a project that requires driving nuts through threaded rods. I keep seeing different numbers for kg.cm and N.m, the explanation kg.cm found on this Stack emphasized only on radial distance, and pulling a weight up against gravity. What gives?

Is there an intuitive way for a not very mathematical noob to calculate how much torque is needed for **loaded**  lead screw actuation?

Comment: It is telling what you need to know but you're stuck in the math box due to unfamiliarity. Force of gravity or applied force, makes no difference. Just most people can grab a weight or scale more easily than a force sensor. Toss some weights at the end of a stick into your loaded setup and see how much weight it takes to make it turn. Or push on the end of the stick with a scale, or drag the end of the stick with a luggage scale. In any case, make sure it is 90 degrees to the stick.

Comment: But if you want to calculate an abstract setup, for most setups it won't be possible unless you are a MechE with all the appropriate data. To be honest your question is super vague. "Loaded lead screw actuation" gives almost zero information. Like asking "how much force does it take to move something?" Full stop. Not what thing, not how to move it, not under what conditions.

Comment: I was asking about an abstract case, hoping someone had a formula for this kind of movement given how popular threaded rods are in moving heavy objects efficiently. I thought the movement being made with a threaded rod and rotation had enough parameters to deduce something that can help me choose a suitable motor for any application. For example, a 3D printer -- a popular application of lead screws. How do I scale up or down the literal ''size'' of this machine? Motors need to be scaled, and if left in the dark.. financial efficiency begins to fade.

Comment: "moving heavy objects efficiently"  Actually no -- a plain threaded leadscrew (not a ball screw) is going to waste a lot of energy in friction.  Basically, you need to know the torque vs. force relation of the leadscrew, which you can either get experimentally, or by computing it from the dimensions and the moments of inertia.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about *Mechanical* Engineering, not *Electrical* Engineering.

Comment: Also, threaded rod blows for movement. Threaded rod is for fastening. You want acme screw or actual lead screws.

Comment: DKs answer should help you but to give you another useful piece, worm gears or screw gears are gears.  Gears have efficiency.  If you remove as much friction as possible from any sliders, you can calculate the force or torque and power necessary to accellerate a given mass at a given rate, and divide that by the efficiency of your drive mechanism to find the necessary output power/torque of your motor.  If you have more than one gear in series, divide the torque needed by each efficiency, one after another.  Primo gears are 98% efficient, but you should assume way worse until you test.

Comment: A slightly overpowered motor will last longer, a slightly underpowered motor will make you sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question technically belongs on the Engineering Stack Exchange since it is a mechanical question.

I won't get into all of it but will just try to give you an outline so you have at least a starting point to muddle around.

1. Once *just enough* force has been provided to overcome the force of
   friction, gravity (travelling on an incline or vertically), and any other forces opposing the linear motion
   of an object are overcome, the object's speed will remain unchanged.
   If it happens when the object is moving at 100m/s, it continues
   moving at 100m/s so long as the applied and opposing forces do not
   change. If this happens when the object is moving at 0m/s, it stays
   moving at 0m/s, however, any additional force applied (i.e. even
   just a tap) will accelerate the object as if it were sliding on a
   frictionless surface and it will start moving. This is the same as
   the difference between simply holding up something up versus
   actually lifting (accelerating) it off the ground.
2. You calculate all the linear forces acting on the mass. That is the minimum force that must be overcome by the set screw. This DOES NOT get the set screw moving. To get the set screw moving, you must then apply additional force to accelerate it as per #1.
3. Therefore as per #2 you must decide on the acceleration required since you do not want to wait forever to get up to speed. You must decide the speed you want the mass to move and how long you're willing to wait for it to get up to that speed. That determines the ADDITIONAL linear force required to be exerted to accelerate the mass.
4. But there's more, you are not just accelerating the mass, when you spin up the motor and the lead screw you are accelerating those as well. This requires the rotary versions of the \$F=ma\$ equations which is \$\tau=I\omega\$ where:

> \$\tau = torque\$,

> \$\omega = angular.velocity (rad/s)\$,

> \$I = moment.of.inertia\$ (the rotational equivalent of mass).

You must read the moment of inertia for the motor off the datasheet, and you must calculate the moment of inertia of the lead-screw by estimating the lead-screw as a cylinder and entering those into the appropriate equation for its moment-of-inertia which you can find in a moment of inertia table table. You will need to convert the speed and acceleration time you decided in #3 to a rotary speed. From this you calculate the EXTRA torque required to spool up motor and lead-screw.

5. A leadscrew is basically a gearbox that converts rotary motion to linear motion (converts rotary torque to linear force). Since it is like a gearbox it also has a gear ratio. The ratio is some amount of linear movement per rotation. Because of this, it is best to calculate the linear forces required to be exerted by the leadscrew and then convert it at the end to the torque with which the leadscrew must be turned at to produce that linear force. You take the linear force calculated in #3, and use the lead-screw ratio to convert it to a torque. Then you add this torque to the torque calculated #5. That gives you the torque required to accelerate the mass and the spool up the motor and lead-screw.
6. Speed is a separate issue. A car that can output infinite torque won't go at infinite speed if it's wheels can't also spin at infinite speed. You can have as much torque as you want on the wheel but it's top speed is limited by RPM. You must find a motor that can provide the torque calculated in #4 when running at your desired speed. You the need to apply a fudge factor to further increase the torque to compensate for lead-screw inefficiency. This number might have to be estimated.
7. This is a real-world calculation where you won't have all the measurements for everything, especially stuff like coefficient of friction or perhaps moment of inertias, and lead-screw efficiency. You can choose to guess values based on intuition, especially if you understand how coefficient of friction relates the pushing force of an object (including one rolling on wheels) to the force required to lift it straight up. In cases of moment of inertia, you could neglect it altogether you feel it if it is small compared to the inertia of the load. Leadscrew efficiency is significant and cannot be neglected. You might have to guess this. 50%? It varies wildly. Do some research.
8. You don't want threaded rod. Those are for fastening. For linear movement you want acme screws or real lead screws.